# Asymptotic expansion of integral with parameter in integrand and limit

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

I would like to understand the asymptotic expansion (or at least, the leading order terms) of

$$ \int_1^\sqrt{x} \sin (2 \pi l t) \ \cos \left(2 \pi k\frac{x}{t}\right) dt$$

as $x$ tends to infinity. I don't know how to deal with the fact that $x$ appears as a parameter in both the limit of the integral, and the integrand. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: if your function is $I_0(x)$, then $I_0'(x) = I_1(x) + f(x)$ where $I_1(x) = -2\pi k \int_1^{\sqrt x} \frac1t \sin(2\pi l t) \sin(2\pi k \frac xt)\,dx$ and $f(x) = \sin(2\pi l\sqrt x)\cos(2\pi k\sqrt x)/2\sqrt x$. One can find the elementary antiderivative of $f(x)$ (via substitution $u=\sqrt x$) which is boundedly oscillating. A similar step can write $I_1'(x) = I_2(x) + g(x)$, and the factor of $\frac1{t^2}$ in the integrand of $I_2(x)$ quickly shows that that function is bounded. So I believe your $I_0(x)$ itself is bounded(!).

Comment: Complexify and look for stationary phase?

Comment: A series of plots `Table[Plot[NIntegrate[Sin[2*Pi*3*t]*Cos[2*Pi*5*x/t], {t, 1, Sqrt[x]}], {x, 
 100* k-10, 100*k}],{k,1,5}]` shows oscillations of the same amplitude and decreasing frequency.

Comment: The commands of Mathematica `f[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sin[2*Pi*3*t]*Cos[2*Pi*5*x/t], {t, 1, Sqrt[x]}]; NMaximize[{RealAbs[
   f[x]], x >= 1}, x, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}]` produce $\{0.0486723,\{x\to 5.07925\}\}$.

Comment: The integral over $[0, 1]$ is $o(1)$. Let $k > 0, l > 0$, $k \neq l$, $t = \sqrt x/u$ and $\phi_{1, 2}(u) = 2 \pi (l/u \pm k u)$. To apply the steepest descent method to $\int_1^\infty u^{-2} e^{i \phi_j(u) \sqrt x} du$, we have to consider the neighborhood of $u = 1$ and the neighborhood of $u = u_0 = \sqrt {l/k}$ if $k < l$. We get
$$\frac k l \sqrt {\frac \pi {2 \phi_1''(u_0)}} \,
  x^{1/4} \sin \left( \phi_1(u_0) \sqrt x + \frac \pi 4 \right) [k < l] + \\
 \frac {\cos(\phi_1(1) \sqrt x)} {2 \phi_1'(1)} +
 \frac {\cos(\phi_2(1) \sqrt x)} {2 \phi_2'(1)} + o(1).$$

Comment: @GregMartin $I_0$ is unbounded if $l > k > 0$.